# Doing something on a specific alt in multiple div class

Tags: jquery

i've some div class which are the same.

```
<div class="user_line">
<img class="delete_user" src="images/close_button_mini.gif">
<a class="chat_user" alt="1|Autozoom" href="#">Autozoom</a>
</div>
<div class="user_line">
<img class="delete_user" src="images/close_button_mini.gif">
<a class="chat_user" alt="2|CREAZ" href="#">CREAZ</a>
</div>
```

I have a jquery var, 
This var could contain 1 or 2 which is the id before | and the username.

I want ti rumble only the div class user which has the id 1 or 2.

```
        // Initialize jRumble on Selector
            $('.user_line').jrumble();
            // Start rumble on element
            $('.user_line').trigger('startRumble');
```

Comment: can you elaborate " the div class user which has the id 1 or 2" it really doesn't make much sense when considered with your html fragment. do you have the ability to edit the output e.g. to add an id attribute to the containing div? or are you wanting to check the `alt` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one number in your variable id use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id=1;
    $("div.user_line").find("a[alt^="+id+"]").jrumble();
});
```

If your id is `Autozoom` then try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id='Autozoom';
    $("div.user_line").find("a[alt$="+id+"]").jrumble();
});
```

If you want to apply `.jrumble()` on multiple divs with multiple id's. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").find("a[alt^=1],a[alt^=2]").each(function(){
        $(this).parent('.user_line').jrumble();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you don't have to use each because in my var id it could be only one number. How can i do it ? you're close

Comment: @user3162341: Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find the div that contain the link with id number of user, you can use

```
var divChatUser = $(".chat_user[alt^='" + id + "']").parent()
```

id is the number of user.

the you can use the object for your purpose